# Tkinter OptionMenu command not entering

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating an OptionMenu in tkinter and assigning it a function to run whenever I choose an option:

```
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *dropdownStr, command=functiona)
dropdown.pack()
```

I also have another function that completely clears out dropdown and re-fills it, since the other function will update or completely change the contents of dropdownStr.

```
var.set('')
dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
for string in dropdownStr:
    dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=string, command=tk._setit(var, string))
```

This works as intended, and the dropdown is updated the way I want. However, from this point on, the dropdown menu no longer calls into functiona. There's no error or complaint, but it's as if I never set the command when creating the menu. I have tried `dropdown.configure` to re-set the command to be functiona, but that doesn't seem to be working. How can I avoid wiping the call into functiona out, or at the very least, re-set it after I clear the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `functiona` as the 3rd argument of `tk._setit()`:

```py
var.set('')
dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
for string in dropdownStr:
    dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=string, command=tk._setit(var, string, functiona))
```